# How can I clean a wireless mouse in which the batteries leaked?

Tags: keyboard, mouse, battery, wireless-mouse, wireless-keyboard

I have a wireless mouse and I noticed that I had stored it with batteries inside.
I know that's wrong because this is what happens:

[image: the mouse was sitting on the keyboard so the acid leaked on that too]
<sup>The mouse was sitting on the keyboard so the acid leaked on that too.</sup>

The batteries were alkaline. One leaked and the acid(?) has completely dried by now.

**→ How do I clean this?**

Comment: You'll probably want some lemon juice/vinegar (for alkaline acid), a cotton bud/old toothbrush to clean the dried acid. If the acid has leaked inside the mouse then you may want to take it apart to see the extent of the leakage... if it's leaked onto the circuit board/optical components then you may consider replacing the mouse entirely.

Comment: Don't know I would recommend lj/v. Most of it may well wipe off with a strong paper towel or similar. Best to wear rubber or nitrile gloves. A toothbrush is always handy to then get into the corners. I'd say get the worst cleaned up then see if it still works before bothering to take it apart.

Comment: I suggest using Q-tips instead of an old toothbrush, they tend to sop up the mess instead of spread it around.